# Tuple and bags to Json

Tags: java, json, mapreduce, apache-pig

I had 4 files. I joined all the files using Pig and obtained the final output and grouped the data as required. Now that I have my input something like this.

({(9723,(N,N)),({({(11,G),(H,House),(1,1ST),(02/25/2015)}),({(10,L),(H,House),(16,EMPTY),(02/25/2015)})})})

which is my pig output.

I want to convert it into JSON.

My output should look like this.

{

```
"department": {

    "department_id": "9723",
    "department_group": {
        "flag1": "N",
        "flag2": "N"
    },
    "employee_detail1": {
        "employee_type": {
            "code": "11",
            "name": "G"
        },
        "employee_level": {
            "code": "H",
            "name": "House"
        },
        "employee_dmg": {
            "code": "1",
            "name": "1st"
        },
        "DOJ": "02/25/2015"
    },
    "employee_detail2": {
        "employee_type": {
            "code": "10",
            "name": "L"
        },
        "employee_level": {
            "code": "H",
            "name": "House"
        },
        "employee_dmg": {
            "code": "0",
            "name": "No"
        },
        "DOJ": "02/25/2015"
    }
}
```

}

There are 2 bags(meaning 2 employee details).... grouped by emp_id and employee group(tuple with flag1 and flag2)....

Can someone suggest me the best way to convert this into JSON...

Comment: your desired output is not valid json. Run it through http://jsonlint.com/ or something so you can validate it.

Comment: I have edited it .... Can u please check now and suggest me the approach of doing it .

Answer (score 0):

You can `STORE` your data with JsonStorage, it will handle nicely a bag.